# Crear carpeta o ficheros con API 30 o superior

Tags: android

Estoy intentando grabar un pdf o crear una carpeta en

```
/storage/emulated/0/Carpeta/fichero.pdf
```

pero con la version API 30 o superior ya no se puede por problema de seguridad.

Pero lo que no quiero es que el usuario final tenga que acceder a

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<Package Name>/files/Carpeta/fichero.pdf
```

para rescatar ese fichero.

Mi pregunta es si en esta version se puede utilizar para este fin las carpetas Documents o Download.

O  en su efecto como lo puedo hacer para que el usuario final lo tenga mas facil

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La forma fácil es pedirle al usuario que te conceda permiso para usar la carpeta que desee para almacenar los archivos.

Según [la documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory), para eso necesitas crear un `Intent` con la acción [`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) y abrir el selector de archivos del sistema con [`startActivityForResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)).

Además puedes especificar la URI de la carpeta en la que se va a mostrar inicialmente en el selector mediante el extra [`EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract#EXTRA_INITIAL_URI).

La documentación ofrece el siguiente ejemplo:

```
public void openDirectory(Uri uriToLoad) {
    // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

    // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
    // the system file picker when it loads.
    intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad);

    startActivityForResult(intent, /* request-code */);
}
```

Para obtener la carpeta elegida por el usuario debes sobrecargar la función [`onActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getData()) y llamar a la función [`getData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getData()) del `Intent` recibido.

Este es un ejemplo de [la documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#perform-operations):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == /* request-code */
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // The result data contains a URI for the document or directory that
        // the user selected.
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            // Perform operations on the document using its URI.
        }
    }
}
```

Si lo prefieres, también deberías poder hacerlo con la API de [ActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) de forma similar.

Comment: Pero, solo con ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE  funciona?

Comment: @Jorgesys cómo? Necesitas usar `onActivityResult` para saber cuál fue la carpeta elegida.